# How to define a root that is obtained by FindRoot as a variable?

Tags: equation-solving, evaluation

Given some function I want to find a root around some value $x=x_0$
so I use FindRoot, for example:

```
root = FindRoot[Exp[x]+Sin[x],{x,0}]
```

But I want the root to be a number such that:

```
root = -0.588533
```

but instead I recieve strange object given by:

```
{x -> -0.588533}
```

how to transform it to a number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some possibilities:

**1. ReplaceAll**

```
  x /. root
```

-0.588533

**2. Values**

```
First @ Values @ root
```

-0.588533

**3. Part**

```
root[[1, 2]]
```

-0.588533

**4. Output structure**

In many situations the "strange object" is very useful, for example:

```
Exp[x] + Sin[x] /. root
```

0. 

Comment: very nicely done. minor thing: isn't this `Values @@ root` a bit cleaner?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I overlooked this posssibility

Answer (score 5):

Less of a solution, more of a comment: `Solve` and `SolveValues` are much more powerful than `FindRoot` and return a `Root` object that can be treated as an exact number. For example,

```
s = SolveValues[{Exp[x] + Sin[x] == 0, -1 < x < 0}, x] // First
(*    Root[{E^# + Sin[#]& , -0.589...}]    *)
```

is the exact number that satisfies the original equation:

```
Exp[s] + Sin[s] // FullSimplify
(*    0    *)
```

is exactly zero, not up to numerical accuracy. You can also evaluate `s` numerically to arbitrary precision:

```
N[s, 100]
(*    -0.5885327439818610774324520457029036885312715161090305333199142995116725533073514277385240615760274096    *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

[`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) can provide multiple solutions.

```
s = Solve[{Exp[x] + Sin[x] == 0, -15 < x < 3}, x]
```

[image]

Verifying the solutions:

```
Exp[x] + Sin[x] /. s // FullSimplify

(* {0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

The roots are exact. Their approximate numeric values are

```
s // N

(* {{x -> -12.5664}, {x -> -9.4247}, {x -> -6.28505}, {x -> -3.09636}, 
  {x -> -0.588533}} *)

Plot[Exp[x] + Sin[x], {x, -15, 3},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{x, 0} /. s]}]
```

[image]

[`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) requires a different initial value for each of the different roots.

```
s2 = FindRoot[Exp[x] + Sin[x], {x, #}] & /@ {-13, -9, -6, -3, -1}

(* {{x -> -12.5664}, {x -> -9.4247}, {x -> -6.28505}, {x -> -3.09636}, 
  {x -> -0.588533}} *)
```

`FindRoot` is less accurate than `Solve`

```
Exp[x] + Sin[x] /. s2

(* {-7.14142*10^-17, 7.1514*10^-16, -1.42681*10^-16, 1.04083*10^-16, 0.} *)
```